# setInterval() function not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to switch the background color from rgb(255,255,255) to rgb(0,0,0) and going through all the possibilities with setInterval between every two colors, but for some reason, at the moment that I activate the function start(), the background color immediately becomes black. does anyone know how to fix this?

I don't have any idea for a solution, so I'm open to any idea.

```
    function start() {

        var red = 255;
        var green = 255;
        var blue = 255;


        var id = setInterval(colorful(), 1000);

        function colorful() {

            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + [red,green,blue].join(",") + ")";


            if (blue == 0) {blue = 0; green--;} 

            if (green == 0) {green = 0; red--;}

            if (red == 0) {clearInterval(id);}

            blue--;

        }
    }
```

I expected to see the background color change and go through all the rgb() colors from 0 to 255, but instead when I run the start() function the screen turns immediately black.

Comment: `colorful` not `colorful()`

Comment: you should use a css transtition for this

Comment: `colorful()` in your `setInterval` call is calling `colorful` and passing its result (undefeined) to `setInternal`. Remove the parentheses to pass the function itself.

Comment: The `setInterval()` function is set to 1000 milliseconds because I tried to check if the timings were the problem, it is supposed to be about 5ms.

Comment: @PhilippSander In this case he needs an CSS animation

Comment: I've reverted the question to the original. If you change the question, the already posted answers won't make sense anymore. If you have a follow-up question, please post it separately.

Comment: Ok, sorry... Simply another problem appeared...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a issue in your code, once fixed it works as expected. 
Remove the brackets from the method passed to setInterval and check the boundaries of your color variables in order to avoid negative values:

```
var id = setInterval(colorful, 100);
```

**Working snippet:**

```js
 function start() {

    var red = 255;
    var green = 255;
    var blue = 255;


    var id = setInterval(colorful, 10);

    function colorful() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + [red,green,blue].join(",") + ")";
        

        if (blue === 0 && green > 0) {green--;} 

        if (green === 0 && red > 0) {red--;}

        if (red === 0) {clearInterval(id);}

        if (blue > 0) blue--;
}}

start();
```

Comment: I was already posting my answer to check if the code would work as expected, in comment I cannot post a working snippet.

Comment: Mosè Raguzzini I tried this, you are right it was the problem, but now a new one popped. It just becomes yellow permanently after a few seconds.

Comment: edited the snippet check your color variables boundaries

Answer (score -4):

It works with your code, if you change the `colorful()` to `colorful` inside the `setTimeout` call. And you need to change the interval duration from `1000` to `5`

But be aware: 5ms is a really short time, it is not guaranteed that it will work that fast.

```js
function start() {

  var red = 255;
  var green = 255;
  var blue = 255;


  var id = setInterval(colorful, 5);

  function colorful() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + [red, green, blue].join(",") + ")";


    blue--;
    if (blue <= 0) {
      blue = 0;
      green--;
    }

    if (green <= 0) {
      green = 0;
      red--;
    }

    if (red <= 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
    }

  }
}

start()
```

You would be better of with a CSS animation.

```css
@keyframes animate-bg-fade-white-to-black {
  0% {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  33% {
    background-color: #ff0;
  }
  67% {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #000;
  }
}

body {
  animation: animate-bg-fade-white-to-black 2s linear both;
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work with OP's code, as this is not OP's code. It works when you FIX IT.

Comment: @vlaz Sorry my bad.